# Alternative to file_get_content (php://input)

Tags: php, ios, curl, file-get-contents, udid

I've recently changed my web hosting and unfortunately the administrator has disabled file_get_content and some other functions.

The aim of this script is to get iOS device's information directly from device. Before, I was using this code to do so:

```
    $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
    file_put_contents("data.txt", $content);
```

And the result was like this (in data.txt)

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>IMEI</key>
    <string>01 257233 621346 0</string>
    <key>PRODUCT</key>
    <string>iPhone2,1</string>
    <key>SERIAL</key>
    <string>5K1124GHEDG</string>
    <key>UDID</key>
    <string>07cc825055gftr4edsa3f06d0373376a7664a66a</string>
    <key>VERSION</key>
    <string>10B329</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

As the Curl function is enabled on my server, I tried this code in some different ways, but didn't work. The data.txt is emptied as a result!

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0;
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "php://input");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    file_put_contents("data.txt", $contents);
```

UPDATED:

Let me explain how it works. We direct users to a profile which is stored on our server(e.g device.mobileconfig). Once users click on that, they will be asked to install that. Its content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
     <dict>
        <key>URL</key>
        <string>http://mywebsite.com/get.php</string>
        <key>DeviceAttributes</key>
            <array>
                <string>UDID</string>
                <string>VERSION</string>
                <string>PRODUCT</string>
                <string>SERIAL</string>
            </array>
    </dict>
    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
    <string>Install to get device info</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>UDID Finder</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.myud.ir</string>
    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
    <string>MyUD.ir</string>
    <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Profile Service</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>57A223FD-F675-90B1-8F43-22D3FC3BC181</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The profile runs get.php to fetch data from device. I tried Cristian's one but did not work. I probably have a mistake some where. The get.php is:

```
<?php
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"><plist version="1.0"/>');
    $dict = $xml->addChild('dict');
    foreach ($_POST as $item => $value) {
        $dict->addChild('string', $item);
        $dict->addChild('key', $value);
    }
    file_put_contents("data.txt", trim(str_replace('<?xml version="1.0"?>', '', $xml->asXML())));
?>
```

P.S.

I just need the data between

```
<dict></dict>
```

Comment: there is also a curl option to set the destination file.

Comment: curl has NO knowledge of php's streams. It expects a proper url, and will rightly complain that `php` is not a known protocol.

Comment: @MarcB: So you mean I can't get data by Curt method?

Comment: no. you'd need to change whatever's sending this data to your script so it uses a proper `key=value` POST submission, so you can get it from $_POST as usual. That or change to a webhost that doesn't have ridiculous lockdowns.

Comment: Is `readfile()` available?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Yes, it is.

Comment: The docs show this example `readfile("php://filter/resource=http://www.example.com");` so maybe it's worth a shot with `readfile("php://input");`

Comment: Disabling `fopen` is not normal — it's a sign of a web host that is going to make your life difficult. Find another web host that doesn't do that.

Comment: @duskwuff: fopen is available.

Comment: @PersianHero: Disabling `file_get_contents` is not normal either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much Cristian. it worked.

I also found another way which is PEAR php Component that provides lots of functions which are alternative to main php functions for those people who are struggling like me!

for instance, in my case, I uploaded the file_get_content function to the same folder and included that in get.php

instead of

```
 $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
 file_put_contents("data.txt", $content);
```

I'm now using

```
require_once 'file_get_contents.php';
$content = php_compat_file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents("data.txt", $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body, you can solve this problem by fetching `$_POST` data then create an xml document using php's `SimpleXMLElement` class witch then will be written to `data.txt`.
You can proceed in this way:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"><plist version="1.0"/>');
$dict = $xml->addChild('dict');
foreach ($_POST as $item => $value) {
    $dict->addChild('string', $item);
    $dict->addChild('key', $value);
}
file_put_contents("data.txt", trim(str_replace('<?xml version="1.0"?>', '', $xml->asXML())));
```

Another solution:

```
$f = fopen('php://input','r');
$out = fopen('data.txt','w');
$body = "";
while( $line = fgets( $f ) ) {
  $body .= $line;
}
fwrite($out, $body);
fclose($f);
fclose($out);
```

Comment: Didn't work. Please review my first post. I added more explanation

Comment: You pass data to your php script in using $_POST ? or $_GET?

Comment: I don't do anything. Once user taps on "install", iOS makes a connection with get.php and sends requested info we have defined in profile(in our case are: UDUD, VERSION, PRODUCT, SERIAL)by $_POST method.
I've recorded a short video of process for you.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOn-sAPnMew

Comment: That means IOS does it in a different way, I mean try to pass some post data to the script then you'll se it works, did you try to change POST to GET?

Comment: "php://input" allows you to read the raw data from a request, rather than relying on $_POST, which will be empty or invalid if the request is using some special format. So it is essential to use "php://input" because firstly, we request some data and iOS will respond us the result of requested data

Comment: Does your web hosting allows you to use file functions? `fopen` , `fwrite`? if so you could read every line of php input stream by opening it as a file, i've edited my answer check it out...